# How to align TextViews to columns of GridView

Tags: android

I am trying to align a row of TextViews on top on a GridView.

The TextViews on top are the days of the week (Mon, Tue, Wed...)

**As you can see the TextViews on the right are not aligned correctly,**

I expected that with `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` I would have gotten it right,

but without success.

[image]

This is my XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/previous"
        android:layout_width="40dip"
        android:layout_height="30dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/arrow_left" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/next"
        android:layout_width="40dip"
        android:layout_height="30dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/arrow_right" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/daysoftheweek"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/sun" 
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/mon" 
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/tue" 
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" 
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/wed" 
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/thu" 
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/fri" 
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" 
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/sat" 
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/daysoftheweek"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    android:numColumns="7"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You should use TablLayout rather gridview because No of boxes are fix. just value of cell is dynamic.

Comment: I would suggest you to use days boxes (Sun/Mon) as the child of Gridview. Simply put condition for style and backgrond for first 7 child of gridview, which are for days....

Comment: @lisa..you have to set textview gravity center for it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// try this
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/previous"
            android:layout_width="40dip"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@drawable/arrow_left" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="18dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/next"
            android:layout_width="40dip"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@drawable/arrow_right" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/daysoftheweek"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/sun"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/mon"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tue"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/wed"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/thu"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/fri"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/sat"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/daysoftheweek"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:numColumns="7"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/previous"
            android:layout_width="40dip"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@drawable/arrow_left" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="18dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/next"
            android:layout_width="40dip"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@drawable/arrow_right" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/daysoftheweek"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/sun"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/mon"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/tue"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/wed"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/thu"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/fri"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/sat"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/daysoftheweek"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:numColumns="7"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Or Try this way

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/sun" 
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:gravity="center"/> // UPDATE HERE to all days textviews
```

Answer (score 1):

Set gravity for your **Linear layout**... of week..

```
android:gravity="center".
```